# Character not glowing with burning embers

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I used to have an undead destruction warlock. I created another human warlock (deleted the undead for some reason). But now, my human warlock does not glow with full burning embers (all 4 generated) like my undead warlock used to. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your warlock should more burn than glow. And more so when you get to four embers. ([Screenshot](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=108647/burning-embers#screenshots:id=316479))

If that is missing check if you have [Glyph of Verdant Spheres](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=56241/glyph-of-verdant-spheres) active. This shows your embers as green spheres around your warlock instead of the burning. ([Screenshot](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=56241/glyph-of-verdant-spheres#screenshots:id=294081))

If that isn't the cause, try changing your graphic settings. Maybe there is something.

Comment: No, I don't have this glyph.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Glyph of Verdant Spheres](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=56241/glyph-of-verdant-spheres)?